# Relating the Jacobian matrix to the total derivative of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Note: I've seen that essentially the same question title has been posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489871/relating-the-total-derivative-and-the-jacobian-matrix), but it does not answer my doubts.

Let $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb R^m $ be a differentiable function. Then the *total derivative* of $g$ at $p \in \mathbb{R}^n $ is the linear function $Dg_p \in L(\mathbb{R}^n , \mathbb{R}^m )$. Therefore it can have a matrix representation once we specify bases for $ \mathbb{R}^n $ and $ \mathbb{R}^m $. Let $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n, \{f_i\}_{i=1}^m$ be the standard bases of $\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m$ respectively.

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) I've seen that the Jacobian matrix $J$ is the matrix representation of $Dg_p$. There the Jacobian is defined as

$$ [J]_{i,j} =  \partial_j g_i, $$

where $\partial _i := \partial/\partial e_i $ and $g_i := e_i^* \circ g $ are the component functions ($e^*_i$ is the dual vector of $e_i$). I'm interested in making the connection between $J$ and $Dg_p$.

By definition of partial derivatives, we know that $\partial _if (p) = Dg_p (e_i)  $. Hence it is that the $i$th column of $J$ is simply $\partial _i f (p)$. This is also shown in the Wikipedia page.

However, the wikipedia also shows that

$$ J = \begin{pmatrix}
\nabla ^Tg_1 \\ \vdots \\ \nabla ^T g_m
\end{pmatrix} ,$$

where, according to Wikipedia, '$ \nabla ^T g_i$ *is the transpose of the gradient of the $i$th component'*.

I do not understand how this equality came about, neither do I understand how can we reach the statement $J_{ij} = \partial _j g_i $ from simply the fact that $g$ is differentiable at $p$ and its total derivative is $Dg_p$

Comment: Take $n=m=2$ and use [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Example_in_two_dimensions) on each component of $g\,.$ Neglect all terms of order two and higher. This shows that $J=Dg\,.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Definition of the Derivative we have
$$
g(p+u) = g(p)+ Dg_pu + o(u).
$$
Where i am using the little o notation for the Derivative.

Now take $u = e_j t$ for $t> 0$ and some $j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$.
Then (using the above and the linearity of $Dg_p$)
$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{g(p+e_jt)-g(p)}{t} = Dg_p e_j.$$
Let $i \in\{1, \dots, m\}$. Since $f^*_i$ is continuous and linear we receive:
$$
\partial_j g_i (p)= f^*_i Dg_p e_j 
$$
and so the matrix representation of $Dg_p$ wrt standard basis is the matrix $(\partial_j g_i (p))_{i,j}$, which is the Jacobian.